# revsere Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given an invertible $m \times m$ matrix $A$ and a full rank $m \times n$ matrix $B$ with $\sigma_{\min}(B) > 0$. Is it true that
$$\sigma_{\max}(AB) \geq \sigma_{\min}(A)\sigma_{\max}(B)$$

It seems intuitive to me, but I am unsure how to prove/disprove it.

If the statement is not true, is there any result similar to this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Note that
$$
\sigma_{\min}(M) = \min_{\|x\| = 1} \|Mx\|, \quad \sigma_{\max}(M) = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Mx\|.
$$
With that in mind, let $x$ be a unit-vector for which $\|Bx\| = \|B\|$. By the above fact about $\sigma_\min$, we can conclude that
$$
\sigma_{\max}(AB) \geq \|ABx\| =  \|B\| \cdot \left\|A\frac{Bx}{\|B\|}\right\| \geq \|B\| \cdot \sigma_\min(A).
$$